# running .bat on ubuntu using wine

Tags: wine, r

I needed to run a .bat file on ubuntu 10.04, so I installed wine and brought up the console.
my .bat file has R scripts, and when I run 
`start test.bat`
I get the following error:
`wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Rscript.exe"`
I know I have R as I use it the regular way, but this is my first experience with wine. any suggestions on how to fix the error....do I need to install R again. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this error, you will need to install R for Windows within Wine.  That should resolve your errors which you are getting.

Comment: thanks @Thomas. since I have never used Wine before, is there anything special I need to do to install it within Wine, or do I just go about the process as if I was working on windows machine...

Comment: @wineRy i'm not an expert with installing things on Wine.  Personally, I run a Windows VM for Windows things, so i'm probably not the best person to ask how to install R within wine.  I'd *assume* the process would be the same, but check http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10560 for compatibility charts of software on Wine.

Comment: (out of comment space)  As well, I'd use the version that has the "Gold" rating for R.  But that's just me.